# handle subquery with joins where same result is to be joined with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery

I have this query which is going through table B twice I want it go through tableB once as I should be able to select all necessary fields from a table once and use that selected result table in multiple joins.
 
    `select tableA.aa,tableA.bb, tableK.address, tableP.address from tableA
        LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        tableB.ID,
        tableB.Address,
        tableD.`Name`,
        tableC.tableCName,
        tableC.Country
    FROM
        tableB
    INNER JOIN tableD ON tableB.tableDID = tableD.ID
    AND tableD.Deleted = 0
    INNER JOIN tableC ON tableD.tableCID = tableC.ID
    WHERE
        tableB.Deleted = 0
) AS tableP ON tableP.ID = tableA.aa
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        tableB.ID,
        tableB.Address,
        tableD.`Name`,
        tableC.tableCName,
        tableC.Country
    FROM
        tableB
    INNER JOIN tableD ON tableB.tableDID = tableD.ID
    AND tableD.Deleted = 0
    INNER JOIN tableC ON tableD.tableCID = tableC.ID
    WHERE
        tableB.Deleted = 0
) AS tableK ON tableK.ID = tableA.bb`

Comment: If Your MySQL version is 8, You can use CTE (WITH clause - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html ).

Comment: @Akina Thanks for reply. MYSQL version I am using is 5.6

Comment: @Akina Sorry as joined on different  values tableA.aa,tableA.bb its not fetching duplicates it is fetching different details from different tables.In fact this query is a part of a bigger query I just cut this section out here as it was bothering. so the need is to avoid full table scan twice.

Comment: The only way I see on Your server version is to convert the subquery to the VIEW form. But I'm not sure... And if You need only one field `Address` from the subquery I think it's safe to remove another fields from its output.

Comment: @akina yes I can remove extra fields but original problem is still there I have written same query subquery twice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have written same query subquery twice

Create VIEW (created once, it exists in database until ALTER or DROP, like tables):

```
CREATE VIEW my_subquery AS
SELECT tableB.ID
     , tableB.Address
--   , tableD.Name
--   , tableC.tableCName
--   , tableC.Country
FROM
    tableB
INNER JOIN tableD ON tableB.tableDID = tableD.ID AND tableD.Deleted = 0
INNER JOIN tableC ON tableD.tableCID = tableC.ID
WHERE
    tableB.Deleted = 0;
```

and then use it in Your query like a common table:

```
SELECT tableA.aa, tableA.bb, tableK.address, tableP.address 
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN my_subquery AS tableP ON tableP.ID = tableA.aa
LEFT JOIN my_subquery AS tableK ON tableK.ID = tableA.bb;
```

Comment: You are awesome...... Best solution... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd9bbc/3

```
select aa, bb, max(paddress), max(kaddress) from ( 
  select tableA.aa,tableA.bb,
    if(tableA.aa = tableP.id, tableP.address, null) paddress,
    if(tableA.bb = tableP.id, tableP.address, null) kaddress
    from tableA
          LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
          tableB.ID,
          tableB.Address,
          tableD.Name,
          tableC.tableCName,
          tableC.Country
      FROM
          tableB
      INNER JOIN tableD ON tableB.tableDID = tableD.ID
      AND tableD.Deleted = 0
      INNER JOIN tableC ON tableD.tableCID = tableC.ID
      WHERE
          tableB.Deleted = 0
  ) AS tableP ON tableP.ID = tableA.aa or tableP.ID = tableA.bb
) A  group by aa, bb;:
```

result:

```
aa  bb      max(paddress)           max(kaddress)
1   2       Langestraat 35 B        (null)
3   4       (null)                  Stationstraat 1
5   6       Weggevoerdenlaan 5B     Veemarkt 5
```

Comment: Thanks... Highly appreciate your effort and help..... but unfortunately your solution is extremely expensive on database and processor I can not afford that anyways thanks.

Comment: Do you have foreign keys defined on your tables?  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ec879/1.  Without them you may be missing a number of indices that could improve performance.